# Invalid JAVA_HOME directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

When I try in console gradlew clean bootRun i see this :

```
ERROR: JAVA_HOME is set to an invalid directory: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin\java;C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_101;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101;C:\Users\ElteGps 022\Desktop\apache-tomcat-7.0.72\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin

Please set the JAVA_HOME variable in your environment to match the
location of your Java installation.
```

This is my JAVA_HOME :

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101\bin
```

Comment: remove the `\bin` part of JAVA_HOME. More info [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/)

Comment: well, now just do what it says: add thymeleaf templates to your project or check your configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A valid JAVA_HOME repertory is: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_101

Don't add "bin" folder, just for path environnemen variable.

Comment: Even after removing "bin" folder from path, it is showing same error. Why isn't it reflecting?